# VSCode dotnet 3.0 attach debugger not working

Tags: debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I just upgraded my whole project to dotnet 3.0 (aspnetCore3.0 and EFCore3.0). Before the upgrade, in VS Code I could attach to the dotnet process and debug just fine.

Now, it asks me to pick the process like it did before, but when I do, the debugger doesn't work. It's not loading any symbols.

I am using this command to run the app in the terminal:

```
dotnet run --project myproj.Web/MyProj.Web.csproj --environment "Development" --server.urls "http://*:5200;https://*:5201;"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try attaching not to dotnet process, but to your_app.exe (even if it is a web application)